# The first 'easy exercise' in Spivak's differential geometry book

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a 'lowly physicist' (actually, only a *prospective* physicist) with little to no background in formal mathematics. Recently I decided it's time to get serious, so I started reading Spivak's 'Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry'. The first chapter, on manifolds, starts off with the definition of a manifold:

**Definition**: A manifold is a metric space $M$ with the property that, for any point $x\in M$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and some integer $n\geq 0$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

On the third page, Spivak argues that $U$ must be an open set. He has already demonstrated that we can always *choose* $U$ to be open. He gives, without proof, the 'Invariance of domain' theorem:

**Theorem**: If $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f: U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is one-one and continuous, then $f(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open. (it follows that $f(V)$ is open for any open $V\subset U$, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous and $f:U\to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism.)

Now, Spivak states that it is 'an easy exercise' to show that this theorem implies that $U$ from the above definition must be open.

I have tried to look up and understand all the relevant definitions. What I (think I) have understood so far is the following. From the property that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ it follows immediately that there is also a homeomorphism (i.e. a continuous and one-one (?) function) from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $U$. If we denote the homeomorphism from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $f$, it is enough to show that $f(U)$ is open to conclude that $f$ is open by the invariance of domain theorem. However, it is not clear to me that this must be the case. Am I missing a subtlety in a definition? Or is there some nontrivial step here?

Comment: Your statement of the "invariant of domain" theorem looks to have an error. One does not say that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one and continuous.

Comment: A homeomorphism is not only one-to-one, but is also *onto* (also called surjective).  Also, the Invariance of Domain theorem should say "$f$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ to its image $f(U)$" (the map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is not necessarily a homeomorphism).  Does this make things a little more clear?

Comment: @JohnM I am not sure I understand the distinction you're trying to highlight in your penultimate sentence. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Considering the $f$ described in the Invariance of Domain theorem, $f: U \rightarrow f(U)$ is a homeomorphism, but $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is not a homeomorphism (unless $f(U) = \mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @JohnM Ah, so this is a subtlety applying to the very last part of my statement of the theorem. I'll adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is to prove that if $U \subset M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $U$ is open. Choose a homeomorphism $f :U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (yes, homeomorphisms are one-to-one, onto, and they are continuous with continuous inverse; also, to be explicit, the topology on $U$ is the subspace topology, whose open sets are the intersections of $U$ with open subsets of $M$).

Take a point $x \in U$. We can *choose* an open subset $V_x \subset M$ containing $x$ and a homeomorphism $f_x : V_x \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The set $V_x \cap U$ is open in the subspace topology on $U$. Therefore $f(V_x \cap U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and it contains $f(x)$. There is an open ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ centered on $f(x)$ such that $B \subset f(V_x \cap U)$. The function $f_x \circ f^{-1}$ restricted to $B$ is one-to-one and continuous, and so by applying the Invariance of Domain Theorem its image $f_x \circ f^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $f_x(V_x)=\mathbb{R}^n$. It follows that $f^{-1}(B) = f_x^{-1} \circ f_x \circ f^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $V_x$ which is an open subset of $M$. Therefore $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $M$. Also, by construction $x \in f^{-1}(B) \subset U$. Since $x \in U$ is arbitrary, $U$ is open.

Comment: It appears the crux of your argument is in the sentence : "The function $f_x∘f^{−1}$ restricted to B is one-to-one and continuous"

I am not sure how this follows from the previous statements (which I think I do understand). Could you elaborate? Is it correct to say that this is because $f$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I also am not sure whether this argument proves that we can always *choose* $U$ open, or whether $U$ *must* be open. In particular, it appears to be very similar to the argument that Spivak presents for the former (which is not what I'm looking for). Could you clarify this issue for me?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, each of $f_x$ and $f$ is a homeomorphism: they are one-to-one, onto, continuous, and have continuous inverses. The same is therefore true of the inverse function $f^{-1}$. The restriction of any homeomorphism to a subset is a homeomorphism from that subset to its image. So $f^{-1}$ restricted to $B$ is a homeomorphism from $B$ to $f^{-1}(B)$. You can now compose that with $f_x$, to get the function $f_x \circ f^{-1}$ restricted to $B$. This is a composition of one-to-one, continuous functions, so it is one-to-one and continuous.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, all I have assumed is that $U$ is a subset of $M$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and what I have proved is that for every $x \in U$ there is an open subset of $M$, namely the subset $f^{-1}(B)$, that contains $x$ and is contained in $U$. So $U$ is a union of open subsets of $M$, implying that $U$ is itself open.

Comment: @LeeMosher This is a little old, but for the benefit of future readers (since this tripped me up): I don't think it's obvious, given Spivak's definition of a manifold, that $V_x$ and $V_y$ are homeomorphic to Euclidean spaces of the same dimension. Indeed this need not be true under Spivak's definition if $x$ and $y$ live in different components of $M$. But I think the trouble could be resolved with a connectedness argument like [this one](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6862961).

Comment: Nitpicking, but in the first sentence of the second paragraph, $x$ should be taken arbitrarily from $U$ rather than from $M$ (the last sentence of the proof makes it clear that the author intended $x \in U$). I tried to edit, but edits have to be 6 or more characters long.

Comment: @AndrewEstrella: After some time I noticed your comment and made the change; I guess authors have more editing authority.